# Silent logout in identity server 3

Tags: javascript, angular, identityserver3

we are using identity server 3 in our application. When user click on logout button at first the identity server logout page will be called then suddenly redirect to our logout page by using "post_logout_redirect_uri". Is there any way to skip identity server logout page.

Comment: Please consider posting a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of what you tried so that others can help you with it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

An workaround we used is of a hidden iframe on your page having as src the identity endsession endpoint (something like: /connect/endsession?id_token_hint={0}&post_logout_redirect_uri={1} )